# Wrapper-macro tactic over extend-type in Clojure failed

Tags: clojure, macros

I've reduced my bigger problem to an artificial MVE (minimal viable example)
using file-io for illustration. My question concerns a certain wrapper macro
that I explain below; it does not concern better ways to use the file-io APIs;
I'm just using file-io to illustrate the macro problem in a small and easy
context. The wrapper macro tactic in my real problem is harder to show and
explain, but this MVE captures the gist of the problem.

Consider the following protocol:

```
(defprotocol Dumper
  (dump [this]))
```

and an implementation over `java.io.File`

```
(extend-type java.io.File
  Dumper
  (dump [file]
    (with-open [rdr (io/reader file)]
      (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
        (println line)))))
```

where we have done a `(:use [clojure.java.io :as io])` to get the `reader`
function. I can use this as follows:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (dump (io/file "resources/a_file.txt")))
```

> ```
> Hello from a text file.
> ```

Now, I want to create another implementation of the protocol, this time over
`java.lang.String`. This implementation wraps the string, treating it as a
file-path string; creates a `clojure.java.io/file`; then calls into the other
implementation of the protocol:

```
(extend-type java.lang.String
  Dumper
  (dump [path-str] (-> path-str, io/file, dump)))
```

and call it like this:

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (dump (io/file "resources/a_file.txt"))
  (dump          "resources/a_file.txt"))
```

> ```
> Hello from a text file.
> Hello from a text file.
> ```

In my real problem, I have many functions in the protocol, and one
implementation just wraps the other in the manner shown. Notice that, in the
wrapper implementation, the method name, `dump`, is replicated. Let's eliminate
that replication with a macro (it's worth doing when the real protocol has many
methods):

```
(defmacro wrap-path-string [method]
  `(~method [path-str] (-> path-str, io/file, ~method)))

(extend-type java.lang.String
  Dumper
  (wrap-path-string dump))
```

Oops, the compiler doesn't like it:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
>   nth not supported on this type: Symbol, compiling:(wrapper_mve/core.clj:18:1)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6688)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
> at clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3072)
> ```

I tried `macroexpand-all`'ing and `macroexpand-1`'ing the macro calls (in CIDER,
difficult to replicate here), and it looks ok. I'm at a loss how to debug
deeper, but perhaps someone here can spot the problem.

Again, I know this MVE has better solutions with the file-io APIs, but I really
want to debug the macro, not find ways to avoid using it, because I need the
wrapper-macro tactic in my real problem.

Comment: Having come across code like this in the wild, and having written some of it myself, I'd urge you to write the functions out by hand, even if it means repeating yourself. If you have to revisit the code in a couple of years, future you will thank you for not having to unpack nested layers of macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `extend-type` is itself a macro, and macroexpansion begins with the outermost form (as opposed to function evaluation, which evaluates each argument before invoking the function). In this case the macroexpansion of `extend-type` is trying to treat the form `(wrap-path-string dump)` as a function body, and is expecting the second item to be an arg vector but finds the symbol `dump`.

If you want to go this route, I think you'll need to write a macro that will produce the desired `expand-type` form with all the function bodies already expanded in place.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Thanks for the confirmation. Your advice above is well taken, too. This might be a case where not-DRY is the right answer.